# Assign array values to Hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array like

```
@arr = ("test1","test2","test3","test4",...);
```

And hashref already has following value

```
$hash->{name} = 'name1';
$hash->{addr} = 'addr';
```

I need to add each array element to hash like

```
 $hash->{array_1} = "test1";
 $hash->{array_2} = "test2";
 $hash->{array_3} = "test3";
..
```

How can I implement this easily?

(I don't need like `$hash->{array_1} = $arr[0];` ... ) . Is there any other method to assign these array elements as hash values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`hash slice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices),

```
@$hash{ map "array_$_", 1 .. @arr } = @arr;
```

or

```
$hash->{"array_$_"} = $arr[$_-1] for 1 .. @arr;
```